# Android - Only execute Gradle task on release build variant

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to configure my build.gradle file to only execute a gradle task when the release build variant is selected. So far, my task always gets executed, whether it is in my  debug or release build types or signing configs. I have tried adding my task inside an applicationsVariants block and check if it is the release variant, but it just loops through all variants.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that both the debug and release tasks always run for whichever build variant you choose. Is it possible to execute some code only when creating a build for release? If so, where does that code go? Thanks!

I have read through every Stackoverflow question on this, but none of the answers really did I am wanting. My end goal is when I select the "release" build variant for a Play Store build, a message is posted to our server. I do not want this to happen when just debugging.

Comment: "My end goal is when I select the "release" build variant for a Play Store build, a message is posted to our server. " So do you want to run a task when a build variant is selected from the IDE Build Variant window?

Comment: Yes. If I select "release" from the Build Variant window, I only want certain tasks to be executed during the build process. If "debug" is selected, those tasks shouldn't be executed.

Comment: Your question is rather misleading. You do not want to execute a certain task upon selecting the Build Variant, but when executing a specific Gradle task (either assembleRelese or assembleDebug). In that case, 'assembleRelease.dependsOn customTask' should do the job.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### Add `doFirst` or `doLast` for the build type you are interested in.

```
android.applicationVariants.all {  variant ->
    if ( variant.buildType.name == "release"){
        variant.assemble.doLast { // Can also use doFirst here to run at the start.
            logger.lifecycle("we have successfully built $v.name and can post a messaage to remote server")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a "No signature of method" error on that first line.

Comment: Try #2 gets me back to my original problem, if I swap "debug" for "release", but set my Build Variant to "debug", the code inside the if statement will still be called on every build.

Comment: @Mark  I think I finally understood you :) I've updated my answer again.

Comment: how we can handle a task on custom build variant?

Comment: for example  if (v.buildType.name == "myCustom"){ } but it not enter

Comment: **Warning:** this may slow down your build. *One of the things we repeatedly see over and over again with people who complain about their slow build is the "doLast". "doLast" is bad, gradle cannot understand if your task is now incremental or not, because it doesn't know what you're doing in there.* https://youtu.be/7ll-rkLCtyk?t=36m4s

Comment: @Mark, is there any way do that outside the variant closure?

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like this to check build version:

```
buildTypes {
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each {output ->
            def project = "AppName"
            def separator = "_"
            /*def flavor = variant.productFlavors[0].name*/
            def buildType = variant.variantData.variantConfiguration.buildType.name
            def versionName = variant.versionName
            def versionCode = variant.versionCode
            def date = new Date();
            def formattedDate = date.format('yyyyMMdd_HHmm')
            if (variant.buildType.name == "release"){
                def newApkName = project + separator + "v" + versionName + separator + versionCode + separator + buildType + separator + formattedDate + ".apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
            }
            if (variant.buildType.name == "debug"){
                def newApkName = project + separator + "v" + versionName + separator + versionCode + separator + buildType + ".apk"
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, newApkName)
            }
        }
    } }
```

Comment: Do your `if (variant.buildType.name == "release"){` and `if (variant.buildType.name == "debug"){` blocks only get run for those build types?